# WalletConnect connection failure iOS client

Tags: wallet-connect

I get the following error when i try  to connect iOS app to walletconnect

```
Task <D190A2B9-E403-4DE1-B9F5-527F29D9D50D>.<1> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://safe-walletconnect.safe.global/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://safe-walletconnect.safe.global/,
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalWebSocketTask <D190A2B9-E403-4DE1-B9F5-527F29D9D50D>.<1>"), 
_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalWebSocketTask <D190A2B9-E403-4DE1-B9F5-527F29D9D50D>.<1>, 
    NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}



Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://safe-walletconnect.safe.global/,
NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://safe-walletconnect.safe.global/}
```

**WC: Connection error: The network connection was lost.
WC: didDisconnect url: https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/**

The used bridge :

```
let bridge = "https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/
```

Can any body help me with this ? any suggestions ?
The same code was working something has changed

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace "https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/" URL With
"https://bridge.walletconnect.org"

Comment: Thank you for the reply

using **"https://bridge.walletconnect.org/"** instead of **"https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/"** does not change anything, the error persists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For me it worked, but had to add the forward / at the end - https://bridge.walletconnect.org/